# Field History Tracking for Territory Field on Opportunity object

Tags: apex, fields, territory-management, field-history

I want to enable field history tracking for `Territory` field (API Name `Territory2`) on `Opportunity` Object. However on field history tracking page, I cannot find that field, so I am not really sure if this field can be tracked. Am I missing something here? There are no documentations regarding the same. As per the documentation -

> You can’t track the following fields:
>
> - Formula, roll-up summary, or auto-number fields
> - Created By and Last Modified By Fields that have the AI Prediction    checkbox selected
> - Expected Revenue field on opportunities
> - Master Solution Title or the Master Solution Details fields on    solutions; these fields display only for translated solutions in  organizations with multilingual solutions enabled.

If it cannot be tracked via the field history tracking page, is there any workaround or can you track field history by apex custom code?  Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks.